# How to update FlatList when a button is pressed in React Native Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

```
export default function App() {
  const [toDoList, setToDoList] = React.useState([
    { task:'dishes', id:'1'},
    { task:'laundry', id:'2'},
    { task:'dishes', id:'3'},
    { task:'laundry', id:'4'},
    { task:'dishes', id:'5'},
  ])

  const [inputText, setText] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={newText => setText(newText)}
        value={inputText}
        placeholder='Input Task'
      />
      
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
        index = toDoList.length + 1
        toDoList.push({ task: {inputText}, id:{index} })
        setToDoList(...toDoList)
      }}>
        <Text style={styles.item}>Add Task</Text> 
      </TouchableOpacity>
      
      <FlatList
      data={toDoList}
      extraData={toDoList}
      renderItem= {({ item }) => ( <Text style={ styles.item }>{item.task}</Text>)}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I want it to add a new item to the flatlist when I click the "Add Item" button, and it should get the task from the TextInput component. When I try it however, It does not update the FlatList in any way. Why is this happening? I think it may be a problem with the toDoList not updating properly, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
    let index = toDoList.length + 1;
    let newTask = { task: `${inputText}`, id: index };
    setToDoList([...toDoList, newTask])
}}>
    <Text style={styles.item}>Add Task</Text> 
</TouchableOpacity>
```